# h:commandbutton with ajax calls wrong action methods

Tags: jsf, action, actionlistener, commandbutton

I have problem with jsf `<h:commandButton>` with `<f:ajax>` tag.  If it has `<f:ajax>` tag, it calls other `action` and `actionListener` methods in the backing bean. If it doesn't have the `<f:ajax>` tag it calls its own right `action` method. 
here is my snippet:

```
 <h:form>
    <h:panelGroup id="loanContent" layout="block">
        <ui:include src="#{mainView.typePage}.xhtml"/>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:commandButton id ="rLoanBtn" value="Create" action="#{mainView.createNewType}">
        <f:ajax execute="loanContent" render="@form"/>
    </h:commandButton>  
 </h:form>
```

if I omit `<f:ajax execute="loanContent"/>` part, it works fine. If I leave as it is, it calls other methods which are responsible for other buttons of the same form. Btw `mainView` backing bean is a `ViewScoped` managed bean.

Comment: Did you try to change execute attribute to something including commandButton in question? Like execute="@this" or "@form" to begin with?

Comment: The dynamic include is causing that. Which JSF impl/version?

Comment: @BalusC After several experiments. I knew that it is not dynamic include. But It calls other methods whatever these methods are before its actual method. I'm using Mojarra 2.1.23 and 2.1.24 is same.

Comment: It goes through other method which is tied to another commandButton component in same view before its own action method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found out cause. If I have `<type = "button">` attribute with other buttons, it goes through methods that is bind to other buttons before its actual method. So I omitted it then it works fine.